# Jekyll category for normal assets

Tags: jekyll

Using Jekyll 2.5.3 I have a collection "_assets" where I would like to store things like:

- .htaccess
- favicon.ico
- apple-touch-icon-*.png

I am using this in _config.yml:

```
collections:
  assets:
    output: true
    permalink: "/:path.html"
```

And the intention is to have these items published to the root directory. However, they are actually being published to a "/assets/" directory.

How can I correct this configuration to output to the intended root directory?

Comment: Why don't you just store them in the root directory?

Comment: Because there are hundreds of files and it is becoming unwieldily